# Redirect by htaccess and adding a string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need two things

1. Redirect all requests from **http://127.0.0.1** to **http://127.0.0.1/cakephp**
2. Redirect all requests from **http://127.0.0.1/somefolder/someaction** to **http://127.0.0.1/cakephp/somefolder/someaction**
3. Do nothing if request is to this page **http://127.0.0.1/cakephp**

I tried this but couldn't make it. Can you recommend the right code?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1/cakephp/$1 [R]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^127.0.0.1 [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1/cakephp/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^127.0.0.1 [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^cakephp(/.*)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cakephp/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: no problem. If you want a good reference, http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php was very helpful for me when I first started writing htaccess redirects